# Error while intalling AWS toolkit for Eclipse Neon

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services

I am trying to install AWS toolkit for eclipse on the eclipe version 4.6.2 (Neon).
I get the following error while trying to do so. Any help?

`Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software currently installed: AWS Toolkit for Eclipse Core (Required) 2.3.1.v201703061745 (com.amazonaws.eclipse.core.feature.feature.group 2.3.1.v201703061745)
Missing requirement: AWS Toolkit Core 2.3.1.v201703061745 (com.amazonaws.eclipse.core 2.3.1.v201703061745) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core 1.5.1' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: AWS Toolkit for Eclipse Core (Required) 2.3.1.v201703061745 (com.amazonaws.eclipse.core.feature.feature.group 2.3.1.v201703061745)
To: com.amazonaws.eclipse.core [2.3.1.v201703061745]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is saying it needs you to have the Maven for Eclipse plugin 'm2e' installed.

You can install m2e from the Eclipse Neon install site.

Comment: Thanks! Solved my issue :)

Comment: Thanks. Worked only if I added new software by URL (http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.5/1.5.1.20150109-1820/). Plugin installation hasn't helped me.

Comment: Fine !  m2e from Oxygen and the aws install after many other plugin installs